# Where to find resources on Refactoring?

Tags: refactoring

Refactoring is the process of improving the existing system design without changing its behavior.

Besides Martin Fowler's seminal book "[Refactoring - Improving the design of existing code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)" and Joshua Kerievsky's book "[Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351)", are there any good resources on refactoring?

Answer (score 7):

http://www.refactoring.com/ might help you. They have a long list of methods here:

- http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/index.html

Joel's article [Rub a dub dub](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000348.html) shows you why you should refactor and not rewrite (but I guess you already knew that rewriting is [a thing you should never do](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)..)

Answer (score 3):

[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) focuses on dealing with existing code-bases that need to evolve to be testable.  Many techniques are used in the book to accomplish this, and is an excellent resource for refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more than just code refactoring, you might find Scott Ambler's book quite useful: http://www.ambysoft.com/books/refactoringDatabases.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [Wiki pages about refactoring](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WikiPagesAboutRefactoring) that explore various principles and guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

What is your codebase?

Eclipse has quite good support for Java. But unfortunately limited support for C++ code.

[Heres](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-eclipse.html) an article from the makers..

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring HTML is new and relatively good, you can guess what it covers :)

Other than that the two books you mention are the two I've used most, but [Agile Principles](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Principles-Patterns-Practices-Robert-Martin/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1221127160&sr=8-1) is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'cheat sheet' for code smells here: http://industriallogic.com/papers/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*, then *Refactoring - Improving the design of existing code*. Martin Fowler's book is more like a receipt book for me, it explains how. Working effectively with legacy code, explains the why in my opinion.

below is some other books relating to refactoring:

[antipatterns refactoring software architectures and projects in crisis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471197130)

[refactoring in large software projects performing complex restructurings](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470858923)

[refactoring sql applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514972)

[Prefactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008740)

Answer (score 0):

Sourcemaking - http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring