# How to find out which specific circular references are present in code

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have some python code where gc.collect() seems to free a lot of memory. Given Python's reference counting nature, I am inclined to think that my program contains a lot of cyclical references. Since some data structures are rather big, I would like to introduce weak references. Now I need to find the circular references, having found a few of the obvious ones, **I wonder if one can detect circular references and the objects that form the ring explicitly**. So far I have only seen tutorials on how to call gc.collect et. al.

Comment: Do these objects have custom `__del__` methods?

Comment: You may find the [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) package useful. It'll create a visualization of the references between objects. [Here's a blog post about circular references and objgraph.](http://engineering.hearsaysocial.com/2013/06/16/circular-references-in-python/)

Comment: I'll also just mention that ideally, you would remove these circular references in the first place, if possible, rather than try to work around them :).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508277/is-there-a-good-dependency-analysis-tool-for-python

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are overriding the `__del__` methods, you should not worry about circular dependencies, as Python is able to properly cope with them.

Comment: ... until you try to use python's multiprocessing and your objects don't pickle anymore. 

IMO it's a good idea to think about how to avoid cyclic references when designing an application, because it keeps several doors open to optimize performance at a later point. That's *not* the same as premature optimization.