# how to list all the packages required for a program in python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip

can i list the python packages that are actually required for running exiting python program running in linux.
I tried running following commands.

```
pip3 freeze 
pip3 list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all modules/packages used by a python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796968/get-all-modules-packages-used-by-a-python-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the modules used by a single python script, you can try to use ModuleFinder:

Create a new python script to analyze the modules your script is using:

New Script:

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('MultiProcess.py')

print('Loaded modules:')
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
    print(('%s: ' % name))
    print((','.join(list(mod.globalnames.keys())[:3])))

print(('-'*50))
print('Modules not imported:')
print(('\n'.join(iter(finder.badmodules.keys()))))
```

The output is very verbose and detailed

reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html