# How does one find out all the python files that imported a given python module?

Tags: python

is there a way to quickly find out who imported a given python module? For example, there is a python module named common.py, I want to find out the whole list of python modules that imported the common.py file.

The project has many files with the same name (there are other files also named common.py). I am interested whether there is any automatic tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796968/get-all-modules-packages-used-by-a-python-project)

Comment: I feel they are two different questions: I am looking for a static way. The above link you pasted assumes there is a binary?